# What is the manuscript evidence for the Joseph Smith Translation of John 4:24

Tags: manuscript, bible-versions

An example of the traditional translation of John 4:24 into English is:

> God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth. (KJV)

There is not much variation in the 38 versions found [here](https://www.biblestudytools.com/john/4-24-compare.html).  All of them start with "God is Spirit" or "God is a Spirit" except for The Message Bible which says "God is sheer being itself - Spirit".  The Message Bible is not really a translation, however, but even still all that has been added is a definition (of sorts) of Spirit and the meaning of the verse has not been altered.

The Joseph Smith Translation (published 1867) renders John 4:24 this way:

> For unto such hath God promised his Spirit. And they who worship him, must worship in spirit and in truth. ([JST John 4:26](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/jst/jst-john/4?lang=eng&id=26#p26)-*2 verses added earlier in JST*)

This is a dramatic shift in meaning from what God ontologically is to what God has promised.

Is there anything in any extant manuscript source that can substantiate this rendering?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146044/discussion-on-question-by-mike-borden-what-is-the-manuscript-evidence-for-the-jo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @Hold to the Rod - The Joseph Smith translation is not based on textual criticism but what He claimed was a "restored" NT text; that is, based on non-Biblical and non-manuscript information.

---

However, to answer the OP's specific question, we have the following facts:

- The text of UBS5/NA28 is: Πνεῦμα ὁ θεός· καὶ τοὺς προσκυνοῦντας αὐτόν, ἐν πνεύματι καὶ ἀληθείᾳ δεῖ προσκυνεῖν.
- UBS5 shows no variation in the text for this verse
- NA28 shows two minor variants of a small number of MSS that do not affect the meaning of the verse.
- The above text agree with the following: TR, Majority text, Byzantine text, SBL, W&H, Orthodox Church text, Souter, THGNT, NIVGNT, etc.
- Even the Latin Vulgate produces an identical result.

The above Greek text is literally translated by:

> God [is] Spirit, and it behooves those worshiping Him to worship in
> spirit and truth."

This is essentially what almost every English version provides.